# Lightinject optional property injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I would like consumers of my nuget package to be able to inject an optional `IConfiguration` implementation. I'm using it along with Umbraco, so it's wired up automatically with Lightinject 5.4.

I've created a property with the optional config:

```
[Inject]
public IConfiguration OptionalInjectedConfiguration { get; set; }
```

The docs state:

> Note:* LightInject considers all read/write properties a dependency, but implements a loose strategy around property dependencies, meaning that it will NOT* throw an exception in the case of an unresolved property dependency.

Yet it throws `Unresolved dependency` for the property. How should I pass this optional dependency?

Comment: I suppose, all properties annotated with the `[Inject]` attribute are required dependencies. The optional dependencies should be declared as settable properties without any annotations.

Comment: @dymanoid Yeah I tried that but it didn't get injected, let me double check... Yep it's null